# Best policy handling bad gift card key/pin attempts in ASP.NET Core

Tags: security, asp.net-core

Got an app where a gift card can be used. A gift card key is requested. What is the best way to handle frequently bad key attempts? Currently we register ip-Addresses of frequently failed requests and ignore further trials after a

```
Thread.Sleep(progressiveDelayTime);
```

This will 'waste' a thread, so guess not the best solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can do `await Task.Delay(progressiveDelayTime)` which won't waste a thread

Comment: Thanks, that is an improvement!

Comment: That's good. Then I'll turn it into an answer. Let's see if someone can suggest another improvement

Answer (score 0):

The easiest improvement would be to use `Task` with `await`. This won't waste a thread at lest

```cs
await Task.Delay(progressiveDelayTime)
```